# Text search on mongodb 2.6 returning error

Tags: mongodb, text-search

I'm using mongoDB 2.6 and the structure of my document is something like this:

```
{
    "about": <about me>,
    "_id" : <id>
}
```

I want to apply text search on about field. I did it using: `db.user.ensureIndex({"about":"text"})`

But when I run a search query: `db.user.find({$text:{$search:"internet"}})` I get this error: `error: { "$err" : "invalid operator: $search", "code" : 10068 }` As per the documentation, text search is enabled on mongodb 2.6 by default. So what could be wrong? Earlier I had 2.2 installed on my machine. I recently downloaded 2.6 and I applied this index using 2.6 only.

Comment: What is the output of db.serverStatus()['version'] run from mongo console?

Comment: @JohnBarça It's giving 2.2. Stopped that server and started on 2.6 and it is working fine now :)

Comment: @coder -- how did you do that . facing same problem ?

Comment: You wouldn't have started mongo 2.6 server. In your client, the output of db.getVersion or db.serverStatus()['version'] would return < 2.6. Just stop that mongod and start 2.6.